# viewing autocomplete.do files

Tags: downloading-website-files

i was trying to reverse engineer a website ("[www.asklaila.com](http://www.asklaila.com)") to find out how their yahoo UI AutoComplete Widget is working. Upon finding the view source of it, i saw it is refering to a file called "/autocomplete.do", i wanted to know what does this autocomplete.do file mean and can i download and open it locally on my machine?

Hope my requisite is legitimate and ethical.

Comment: Don't mean _ethical_ instead of _unethical_?

Comment: You hope it's unethical? Dare I ask why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by [FileInfo.com](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/do), the .do extension represents a server side Java code file that runs on the server and outputs HTML to the response.

Therefore, you cannot download it and view its contents. Any requests to the file will either return the same HTML or an HTTP error if it requires parameters/form fields.

Comment: yeah i got that, but is there any thing i can do from my local machine to understand how that code will be working? By impersonating or passing some data? How can i get to do that?

Comment: I would not be so naive as to assume that the security restrictions on the file would be poor, but even if they are, you would be moving into unethical territory, if you try to hack the server by attempting impersonation.

Comment: i too thought that i will be entering the unethical territory, i don't know if it is the right place to ask, but how can i get to that unethical territory? Do you have any resources? is it proper to ask here?